# Styling table created with javascript

Tags: html, css, styling

I want to style my table I created with javascript like:

```
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  var thead = document.createElement('THEAD');
  table.appendChild(thead);
  var trhead = document.createElement('TR');
  thead.appendChild(trhead);
var headers = new Array("Date", "Event", "Artist");
  for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      var tdhead = document.createElement('TD');
      bold = document.createElement('strong'),
      textnode = document.createTextNode(headers[x]);
      bold.appendChild(textnode);
      tdhead.appendChild(bold);
      tdhead.style.color = "#212529";
      tdhead.style.fontWeight="bold";
      trhead.appendChild(tdhead);
  }
  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);



  for (i=0;i<total;i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    var dategig = json.data[i].date.value;
    var dategig = dategig.split('T')[0];
    var artist = json.data[i].artist.name
    var event = json.data[i].eventName
    var arr = new Array(dategig, event, artist);
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');
      textnode = document.createTextNode(arr[j]);
      td.appendChild(textnode);
      td.style.color = "#212529";
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
  myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
```

As you can see I already can assign a color to the cells.
Now I want to add a border-bottom to the TR element:

```
tr.style.border= "1pt";
```

But that doesn't change anything on the table..
also "border-bottom" is not recognized as an style attribute, why?

---

Comment: There is not any jquery in use here? The javascript property equivalent is `borderBottom` and not `border-bottom`. See [this info](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_borderbottom.asp)

Answer (score 1):

`tr` doesn't have a border property.  Apply it to the `td` instead.

**CSS:**

```
td { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
```

**JS:**

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var tdCount = document.getElementsByTagName("td").length;
for (var i=0; i<tdCount; i++) {
    td[i].style.borderBottom = "2px solid orange";
}
```

**jQuery:**
`$('td').css('borderBottom', '2px solid blue');`

Answer (score 0):

As @thingEvery say, tr doesn't have border by default, BUT you can sort of hack it with `linear-gradient` [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient). Example:

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
tr {background-image: linear-gradient(white 0px, white 16px, black 16px, black 100%);}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```